# Android WebView - YouTube video redirects to main page

Tags: android, youtube, android-webview

I try to open YouTube links by click on item in RecyclerView and load it in WebView. But instead of loading https://m.youtube.com/watch?feature=youtu.be&v=32yY_kDOqls it redirects on wrong page https://m.youtube.com/?client=mv-google
When I search this video on YouTube, it opens.
WebView settings:

```
private void initWebView() {
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
        webSettings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
        webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webSettings.setDisplayZoomControls(false);
        webSettings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
        webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webView.setDrawingCacheBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        webView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        webView.setFocusable(true);
        webView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
        webView.setWillNotCacheDrawing(true);
        webView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(true);
        webView.setSaveEnabled(true);
        webView.setNetworkAvailable(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(presenter.provideWebViewClient());
        webView.setWebChromeClient(presenter.provideWebChromeClient());
    }
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

- Try this
  Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(URL));
          activity.startActivity(browserIntent);
- Try to get normal url from mobile url before passing it to Uri.parse